# Java 11 doesn't run main method if the public class is not declared first

Tags: java

I created the following `Chimpazee.java` file with the following content:

```java
class Primate {
    public Primate() {
        System.out.print("Primate-");
    }
}

class Ape extends Primate {
    public Ape(int fur) {
        System.out.print("Ape1-");
    }
    public Ape() {
        System.out.print("Ape2-");
    }
}

public class Chimpazee extends Ape {
    public Chimpazee() {
        super(2);
        System.out.print("Chimpazee-");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Chimpazee();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to execute this file on Windows 10 + PowerShell using Java 11...

```sh
PS C:\projects\ocp-java-se\java-se-11\chapter8> java -version
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)
```

I'm getting a runtime error with the following command

```sh
PS C:\projects\ocp-java-se\java-se-11\chapter8> java .\Chimpazee.java
error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Primate
```

If I move the Chimpazee class to the beginning of the file it works fine. Isn't suppose to Java compile this independent of the sequence of the classes?

Comment: It works fine if I rename the file to Chimpanzee.java and if I compile it first.

Comment: hopefully it's a typo in the last code block that you're trying to run "Chimpazee.java" instead of Chimpanzee.java (missing an 'n')...

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but I fixed. But the error continues

Comment: The point is, if I compile using `javac Chimpazee.java` the JDK generate three .class files, one for each class. Then I can run it using `java Chimpazee`. The new bit of JDK 11 that doesn't work `java Chimpazee.java`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) mentions it as:

> The class to be executed is the first top-level class found in the
> source file. It must contain a declaration of the standard public
> static void main(String[]) method.

i.e. you need to make `public class Chimpanzee` as the top-level class as follows:

```
public class Chimpanzee extends Ape {
    public Chimpanzee() {
        super(2);
        System.out.print("Chimpanzee-");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Chimpanzee();
    }
}

class Primate {
    public Primate() {
        System.out.print("Primate-");
    }
}

class Ape extends Primate {
    public Ape(int fur) {
        System.out.print("Ape1-");
    }
    public Ape() {
        System.out.print("Ape2-");
    }
}
```

Then, run it as

```
java Chimpanzee.java
```

**Output:**

```
Primate-Ape1-Chimpanzee-
```

Comment: That's right, I got confused because you can compile using `javac` and run using `java`. But not compile+run in memory using `java <file name>.java`. Thanks